# Oval Rotor Q-rings impossible (for me) to dial in on (new) OPEN U.P. with SRAM Force AXS D1 FD

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front, chainring-oval

For a long distance dream build, I chose the latest OPEN U.P. frame and a Force D1 groupset with oval Rotor 48/35 Q-rings.

I'm no stranger to setting up oval chainrings since I've had O.Symetric and absoluteBLACK chainrings on multiple bikes in multiple configurations over the years, ranging from sub-compact all the way to a massive 56t chainring (for KOM hunting). They all had Shimano Di2 in common.

However, OPEN, Rotor, and AXS are new to me. The U.P. frame for instance has a seat-tube angle optimized for seat-posts without off-set and the front derailleur braze-on mount height is to low for for the oval 48t chainring, so I've re-used an old O.Symetric shim to both rise and move the FD further back.

I've never had to use shims with absoluteBLACK setups but they've always been necessary with O.Symetric chainrings. [image]

As Art's Cyclery points out in a video about setting up oval 2x, they're usually beneficial cf: https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxSqKUrPbgjnZku_Q3XlXpHLgpPLjfeW7d

[image]

Unlike QXL chainrings however, Q-rings don't come with one (and are akin to absoluteBLACK, so shouldn't need one), and I understand it can be angled. The smaller one Art says is for Q-rings, I can't seem to source anywhere.

In other words, how do one setup a SRAM Force AXS D1 FD with 48/35 Rotor Q-rings on an OPEN (new) U.P. frame?

I've spent countless hours on this and am going crazy, and a lot of events and races are coming up...

Comment: Is one of the wedges still able to fit right even with the shim moving the FD back and further away from the tube?

Comment: It would be helpful to include some pictures and/or more explanation of what's going wrong. Is the shim moving the FD too far back and creating too much gap with the rings? Is it shifting badly or not at all?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Nathan. I've since I posted my question learned that the wedges that come with an AXS FD can play a role in shifting performance. Not that that ever has been something to consider with Di2, but I'll give some proper tuning and see how it goes. Furthermore, I've ordered the QXL shim with an angle to cover that base as well.